# Issue with image and link alignment

Tags: html, css, styling

So i've got this issue with my CSS where I cannot display a text-link inline with my image.
The links are on a different height relative to my image? What can the issue be? I've tried using different alignment methods such as vertical-align etc.

Maybe I should rewrite the whole code?

```
html,
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

.left_div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.left_div img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2vh 0 2vh 0;
}

.left_div a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(217, 50, 141);
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 2vh auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.left_div a.active {
    background-color: rgb(65, 29, 100);
    color: white;
}

.left_div a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgb(153, 22, 94);
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 765px) and (max-width: 968px) {
    .left_div {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .left_div img {
        width: 12.5%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
    }

    .left_div a {
        display: inline;
        color: black;
        background-color: rgb(217, 50, 141);
        padding: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 765px) {
    .left_div {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .left_div a {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
}

<!-- HTML -->


    <div class="left_div">

        <img src="img/mlp_logo.png" alt="My Little Pony Logo">


        <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">News</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle to show the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/bcyu0f52

Thanks!

edit (screenshot added)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6S4L.jpg
As you see on the screenshot the image and text are misaligned height-wise.

Comment: you can point to screenshot what is exact issue. because in jsfiddle its seem like ok

Comment: everything seems to be in order, just like aviboy2006 said ?

Comment: I think you want to have your `a` tags vertically aligned with the image, right? If so, add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.left_div img`. Updated fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/pkd5ygwh/1/)

Comment: @SaschaM78 wow, what a noob mistake by me. Thank you a lot! haha. Hope everyone have a great upcoming weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, setting the proper vertical alignment did the trick:

Solution was to add:

```
.left_div img {
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @SaschaM78.

> I think you want to have your a tags vertically aligned with the image, right? If  so, add vertical-align: middle; to .left_div img. Updated fiddle can be found here - @SaschaM78

Thanks! A little noob mistake by me.

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things we miss :-). Would it be OK if I write a short answer?

Comment: @SaschaM78 Sure! Go for it!

Comment: Thanks mate, just added a summarized answer. Have a nice weekend!